# ValueError: The view users.views.logout_user didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I am building a blog app in django. But, when I write a function for logging users out, I get this traceback error:

```
Internal Server Error: /users/logout/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 186, in _get_response
    self.check_response(response, callback)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 309, in check_response
    "instead." % name
ValueError: The view users.views.logout_user didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

My `logout_user` view function is only two lines, so I can't seem to understand the error. Here is my view function:

```
@login_required
def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You should pass any response or redirect page

Comment: Do you mean redirect after the logout? Because I have already specified LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL in my settings file

Comment: Look you error specific. `The view users.views.logout_user didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`. Return any response then try again

Comment: Yeah it works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the view must return `render` response. You should something redirect `HttpResponseRedirect()`

```
return HttpResponseRedirect()
```

To log out a user who has been logged in via `django.contrib.auth.login()`, use `django.contrib.auth.logout()` within your view. It takes an `HttpRequest` object and has no return value.

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    # Redirect to a success page.
```

Comment: It would be great if you added the redirect within the last piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you and fixed it as followed:

```py
@login_required(login_url='users/login/')
def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('homepage')
```

where homepage is defined in views.py as:

```py
def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'main/homepage.html')
```

and imported into the main urls.py

```py
from main.views import homepage

urlpatterns = [
path('', homepage, name='homepage'),
]
```